# Fallout 4 starts in Small Window at Top Left Hand Corner of Screen?

Tags: fallout-4, monitor

I bought Fallout 4 recently (finally more like it), and wanted to play the game. So I launched it, and popped up in a small window on the top left hand side of my screen. I went into to game settings and tried to tinker with the settings to see if that may work, it didn't.

The game itself is playable, as normal, but the problem is that it keeps popping up in a small window.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Does your setup include more than one monitor? In the game's settings, is the resolution set to your monitor's resolution? We need more info before we can help.

Comment: Are you running in full screen or windowed mode?

Comment: @pushasha I am using one monitor

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Full Screen mode

Comment: Is there any chance you could take a screenshot/picture of what's happening?

Comment: Im not at my pc right now unfortunately. Whenever I launch the game, it loads momentarily, and then a small window pops up with the menu. You cant move the window from the top left hand side of the screen

Comment: I did some research and it looks like theres a conflict in the games .ini files? Whatever that is.

Comment: Have you tried running in borderless windowed mode rather than fullscreen? You can set it in the launcher settings menu. That's what people seem to be suggesting on various forums.

Comment: Hmm. Never taught of that. Will give it a shot when I get back to my pc

Comment: Conflict on the game's .ini files? Those are files located in your My Documents/My Games/Fallout 4 folder, and are related to configuration of the game. Maybe try validating the game cache through Steam?

Comment: I would never have taught of that. Will try it asap if the first solution doesnt work. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't see any ini files where they should be, you need to run as admin (permanently set the shortcut as such or your saves might not work either). Google your title (it's always easier to google something once you write a concise question title ;)

Comment: as nobody has mentioned this or asked this: What are your specs (notably graphics)? are you on a full desktop or a laptop?

Comment: I dont think it really matters now. I solved the problem with pushasha's solution. My specs is a Asus ROG laptop with a core i7 7700hq and a gtx 1050ti 4gb gpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a late answer to this question, but better late than never right?

So, to combat this problem, I had to open and modify the Fallout4Prefs.ini file found in the Fallout4 directory in my Documents.

I changed the following settings to the resolution of my monitor (1920x1080), as well as altering other settings to make the game work.

iSize W -> 1920

iSize H -> 1080

iBorderless -> 1

Once these settings were saved, and the game loaded up, the game launched at full resolution with no problem whatsoever.